# How to set a class member to a default value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to implement a function that: uses templates, takes an object from an array, turns the object into a default value (say "none" or 0). Is there a way to do this without deleting the object from the array and re-adding it?

```
class Dozen
{
private:
    ItemType data[12];  // array storage
    int  thesize;  //number of non-default values in the currently stored
    //ItemType value;
public:
    ItemType value;
    Dozen();
    Dozen(ItemType val);   //fills the new object with the default value provided
    void insert(ItemType val);  //stores val at position index
    ItemType  reset(ItemType index);  //resets element to default value
    ItemType largest();   //returns largest in the collection
    ItemType smallest(); //returns the smallest in the collection
    int count(ItemType val); //returns the number of times val occurs in the collection
    void display();  //displays all items in the collection
};
```

This is my class so far... I'm using both types int and string. What is the best way to reset the object in the array to a default value for both types?

Comment: `data[index] = ItemType();` will assign a default constructed object to your array, which I think its what you are asking for.